# Multiple \publishers in KOMA-Script

Tags: xetex, koma-script, scrreprt

I would like to print multiple `\publishers{}` on my title page with KOMA-Script. I'm using the `scrreprt` document class.

So far I've tried:

```latex
\publishers{Publisher A}
\and
\publishers{Publisher B}
```

and

```latex
\publishers{
  Publisher A
  \and
  Publisher B
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Misplaced \crcr.
\endtabular ->\crcr 
                    \egroup \egroup $\egroup 
l.118 \begin
```

Comment: I have a work-around that goes like this:
`\publishers{Publisher A\\ \bigskip Publisher B}`

Comment: It seems that you work-around is the correct solution, but you may use the option space setting `[<vspace>]` to the ``\\`` command, i.e. `\\[2ex]`